# Alternative to Unity Web Search Lens

Tags: unity, search, lenses

This lens stopped working in Ubuntu 11.10. Does anyone know of any alternatives that work in Ubuntu 11.10? This is a useful lens that I miss having in Ubuntu 11.04.

Comment: I presume you are talking about this (https://launchpad.net/~cscarney/+archive/unity-web-place/+packages) ?  There is an oneiric package available in that PPA.  Have you contacted the PPA maintainer with your issue?  Can you expand "stopped working" - stopped how?  Is it visible, not visible?

Comment: Could you make that link into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I presume it was this Natty lens you were referring to from [this ppa](https://launchpad.net/~cscarney/+archive/unity-web-place/+packages)

[image]

Whilst there is an oneiric package in the PPA it looks like it hasnt been touched since May 2011.  When installing it gives a dependency error.

I've tried rebuilding with a dependency fix for oneiric but when running it fails due to an out-of-date use of python.

This does look like an interesting lens - but perhaps really should be part of the [Unity-Scopes blueprint](https://blueprints.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+spec/desktop-p-100scopes) - if you agree, post a request indicating where the current code resides and hopefully if agreed, the developers can rework this into a scope.